# Jquery Validate changing page before php script runs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I am new to PHP MYSQL JQUERY and I have a Jquery Mobile Form that i want to submit the form data to mySql then change to #pageTwo of the mobile page. This seems like it should be easy to do but i cant seem to figure it out.

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <?php include 'connectDB.php' ?>
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Order Request Form</h1>
  </div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
 <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <form method="post" id="ACform" name="ACform">        
      <div>
      <label for="onSiteName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">On Site Contact:</label>
      <input type="text" name="onSiteName" id="onSiteName" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="On Site Contact name..." required>
      </div>
      <div>
      <label for="onSiteNumber" class="ui-hidden-accessible">On Site Contact Number:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="onSiteNumber" id="onSiteNumber" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="On Site Contact number..." required>
      </div>
      <div>
      <label for="adminContactName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Administrator Contact:</label>
      <select name="adminContactDropDown" id="adminContactDropDown" required>
        <option value="">Admin Contact</option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
        <option value="bar">bar</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
          </div>
          <div>
          <input type="text" name="adminContactName" id="adminContactName" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Administrator Contact name..." required>
          <label for="adminContactNumber" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Administrator Contact Number:</label>
          <input type="tel" name="adminContactNumber" id="adminContactNumber" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Administrator Contact number..." required>
      </div>
<script>
     $('#ACform').validate({
      messages: {
        onSiteName: {required: "Please enter the on-site contact name"},
        onSiteNumber: {required: "Please enter the on-site contacts number"},
        adminContactDropDown: {required: "Please select an admin contact"},
        adminContactName: {required: "Please enter an admin contact name"},
        adminContactNumber: {required: "Please enter an admin contact number"},
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter($(element).parent());
        },
       submitHandler: function (form) {
          form.submit();
          ':mobile-pagecontainer'.pagecontainer('change', '#pagetwo',     {
           reload: false
              });
           return false;
           }
        });
</script>
 <?php include 'submit.php' ?>
     <div>
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" id="clear">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br/>
     </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1><img src="logo.png" align="middle" width="160" height="26"/></h1>
  </div>
</div>  

<!--Page two-->
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="pagetwo">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>A/C Order Request Sent!</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
       <?php echo $output; ?>
    <p>Thank you for submitting your order request. Your request will be reviewed by one of our sales representatives and you will be contacted shortly.</p>
    <div align="right"><a href="#pageone" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right">Place another order</a></div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1><img src="logo.png" align="middle" width="160" height="26"/></h1>
  </div>

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

submit.php

```
    <?php $jobName = $delDate = $delTimeFrom = $useDate = $startTime = $puDate = $puTimeFrom = $address = $address2 = $zip = $city = $state = $delArea = $onSiteName = $onSiteNumber = $adminContactName = $adminContactNumber = $ACtotal = ''; 
    if ($_POST) {
  $onSiteName = test_input($_POST["onSiteName"]);
  $onSiteNumber = test_input($_POST["onSiteNumber"]);
  $adminContactName = test_input($_POST["adminContactName"]);
  $adminContactNumber = test_input($_POST["adminContactNumber"]);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_orders (onSiteName , onSiteNumber , adminContactName , adminContactNumber)
    VALUES ('$onSiteName' , '$onSiteNumber' , '$adminContactName' , '$adminContactNumber')";}

    function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;}

       $output = '';
       if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
$output .= "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        $output .= "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    ?>
```

I have tried to remove the submitHandler, it submits the form properly but it doesnt change the page and disrupts all the other javascript on the page (not shown) when it reloads. But when i have the submitHandler in, the page changes but the form doesn't submit.

## edit

Based on Michaels suggestion, i tried the below code which gave me an "error loading page" error:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
  $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pagetwo', {
   reload: false
  });
 return false;
}
form.submit();
});
```

I also tried:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
  $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pagetwo', {
   reload: false
  });
 return false;
 form.submit();
}
});
```

which took me to pageTwo but did not submit the form

Comment: Did the `form.submit();` suggestion not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `submitHandler` method, you then need to submit the form. Check here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

For sake of clarity, I've removed the first edit.

**EDIT #2**

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<!-- Added the head just to make sure everything is included -->
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Page One -->
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Order Request Form</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <form method="post" id="ACform" name="ACform">        
                    <div>
                        <label for="onSiteName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">On Site Contact:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="onSiteName" id="onSiteName" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="On Site Contact name..." required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="onSiteNumber" class="ui-hidden-accessible">On Site Contact Number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="onSiteNumber" id="onSiteNumber" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="On Site Contact number..." required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="adminContactName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Administrator Contact:</label>
                        <select name="adminContactDropDown" id="adminContactDropDown" required>
                            <option value="">Admin Contact</option>
                            <option value="foo">foo</option>
                            <option value="bar">bar</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="adminContactName" id="adminContactName" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Administrator Contact name..." required>
                        <label for="adminContactNumber" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Administrator Contact Number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="adminContactNumber" id="adminContactNumber" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Administrator Contact number..." required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" id="clear">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>
                <img src="logo.png" align="middle" width="160" height="26"/>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <!--Page two-->
    <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="pagetwo">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>A/C Order Request Sent!</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div id="dbOutput"></div> <!-- Added as placeholder for DB output -->
            <p>Thank you for submitting your order request. Your request will be reviewed by one of our sales representatives and you will be contacted shortly.</p>
            <div align="right">
                <a href="#pageone" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right">Place another order</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>
                <img src="logo.png" align="middle" width="160" height="26"/>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('#ACform').validate({
        messages: {
            onSiteName: {required: "Please enter the on-site contact name"},
            onSiteNumber: {required: "Please enter the on-site contacts number"},
            adminContactDropDown: {required: "Please select an admin contact"},
            adminContactName: {required: "Please enter an admin contact name"},
            adminContactNumber: {required: "Please enter an admin contact number"},
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter($(element).parent());
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var data = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submit.php',
                data: data,
                success: function (response, status){
                    console.log(response); //This should show the $output variable from submit.php
                    $('#dbOutput').innerHTML(response); //This will input the response into the div#dbOutput
                    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pagetwo'); //According to samples, this should be correct code... But again, I've never actually used pagecontainer
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The connectDB.php file:

```
<?php
$config = [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'joe',
    'password' => 'thisismypassword',
    'dbname' => 'databasename'
];
$db = new PDO('mysql: host='.$config['host'].';dbname='.$config['dbname'],$config['username'],$config['password'];
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttrebute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The database table:

```
+--------------------+
| tbl_orders         |
+--------------------+
| id                 |
| onSiteName         |
| onSiteNumber       |
| adminContactName   |
| adminContactNumber |
+--------------------+
```

The `submit.php` file:

```
<?php 
include 'connectDB.php';

$jobName = $delDate = $delTimeFrom = $useDate = $startTime = $puDate = $puTimeFrom = $address = $address2 = $zip = $city = $state = $delArea = $onSiteName = $onSiteNumber = $adminContactName = $adminContactNumber = $ACtotal = ''; 
//Check to make sure the there are values and that they aren't false values before proceeding
if (isset($_POST['onSiteName']) && !empty($_POST['onSiteName'])) {
    $onSiteName = test_input($_POST["onSiteName"]);
    $onSiteNumber = test_input($_POST["onSiteNumber"]);
    $adminContactName = test_input($_POST["adminContactName"]);
    $adminContactNumber = test_input($_POST["adminContactNumber"]);

    //Preparing the query to avoid SQL injection
    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_orders (onSiteName , onSiteNumber , adminContactName , adminContactNumber)
VALUES (:onSiteName , :onSiteNumber , :adminContactName , :adminContactNumber)";
    //Binding the parameters
    $sql_params = [
        ':onSiteName' => $onSiteName,
        ':onSiteNumber' => $onSiteNumber,
        ':adminContactName' => $adminContactName,
        ':adminContactNumber' => $adminContactNumber
    ];

    $output = '';
    if ($sql->execute($sql_params) === TRUE) {
        $output .= "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        $output .= "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    echo $output;
}
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlentities($data); //changed from htmlspecialchars to make sure most symbols are encoded properly for storage in DB
    return $data;
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

I've updated the answer to include all necessary components. Also, I don't know how you're connecting to your database, but I use PDO to connect to databases, so if you use something other than that, you'll need to adapt the code. Basically, you will post the form using AJAX to your submit.php script which then processes and tries to insert into the DB. Then it `echo`s the `$output` variable which AJAX will catch as the `response` and will log it in your console as well as change it in your new div titled `#dbOutput`. Basically, the output wouldn't change because the PHP had already served to the page, so it was done. Using AJAX will allow you to, without reloading the page, dynamically change an element with results from the DB. You'll have to comb through carefully as there were several minor corrections/edits. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Michael Thank you for your response. The formSubmit gave me an "error loading page" message. I have revised my post with the different variations i have tried

Comment: @AndrewMetzger Have you tried commenting out the `.pagecontainer` code to see if that may be contributing? Basically, you want to boil things down to the absolute necessary things, make it work and then start adding things back in.

Comment: I did remove the `.pagecontainer` code and it processes the form properly but it doesn't redirect to #pageTwo and reloads pageOne with javascript errors.

Comment: Are you open to using AJAX?

Comment: @AndrewMetzger I've made edits to the form portion of the HTML and the javascript portion of the script. Also, you had the script in the middle of the `<form>` tag, which was incorrect. All javascript should be placed either at the beginning or ending of the page. Your form element didn't have a `action` either and because you used `form.submit()`, I assume that all of this was being submitted via the same `.php` page. So, it looks like there may be more to getting the code to work than just functioning code. Try to think of the flow you're going for. Map it out if necessary, then code to that

Comment: I think that you are absolutely right, I am going to rethink the layout. I tried your suggestion and that still didn't do it, so it must be a bigger issue. The page changed, but the form did not submit. It must be an issue with my PHP script.